# How to include GeoLite2 database in a java application

Tags: java, maxmind, geoip2

I'm new in Java programming so don't hold it against me. I'm trying to include a `Maxmind` database in my application. I've been using a relative path when working on the project, similar to:

```
File dbfile = new File("C:\Development\Maxmind GeoIP2 DB\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
DatabaseReader dbReader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(dbfile).build();
```

That works well for local development, however I've been struggling to figure out how to add the database file when I compile the project.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308388

Comment: What you want is to put the file in the same dir as your class and use getResourceAsStream()